# how to export modules in subfolders without including /lib folder in import statement

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, module, nwb

i'm using [nwb](https://github.com/insin/nwb/) to create a new library.

using default settings, nwb will use build project to cjs and es6 and umb and include builds in /lib folder

example project structure

```
-src
  --ModuleA
    --- index.js
    --- helperForA.js
  --ModuleB
    --- index.js
    --- helperForA.js

  index.js
-lib
  --ModuleA
    --- index.js
    --- helperForA.js
  --ModuleB
    --- index.js
    --- helperForA.js

  --index.js
-package.json
```

now when i install them into another project i cannot access subfolders without adding /lib prefix first

when i npm install my library into another project currently i have to do

```
import {A} from 'testLibrary/lib/ModuleA'
```

but what i want is to do

```
import {A} from 'testLibrary/ModuleA'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `src/index.js` to re-export the contents of your library, as per the [Libraries docs](https://github.com/insin/nwb/blob/master/docs/guides/ReactComponents.md#libraries):

```
export A from './ModuleA'
export B from './ModuleB'
```

Comment: i do re-export, but does not that mean that user must use `import {A} from 'root'` ? or by re-exporting it automatically enable `import A from 'root/A'` ?